# Visa for taking the New York Bar Exam?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, study

I will be sitting the New York bar exam in a week and just sorted out my ESTA stuff online. I was wondering is my purpose for travelling covered under the Visa Waiver Programme. Do I need a different visa is my main worry?

Answer (score 7):

If you qualify for a VWP/ESTA then visiting in order to conduct forms of business where you aren't being paid is normally permissible:

> The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) allows citizens of participating countries* to travel to the United States without obtaining a visa, for stays of 90 days or less for tourism or business. ...
>
> The following are examples of activities permitted 
>   while in the United States on the VWP. 
>   * consult with business associates * attend a scientific, educational, professional, or business convention or conference * attend short-term training (you may not be paid by any source in the United States with the exception of expenses incidental to your stay) *negotiate a contract ([Source](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html))

While test taking is not explicitly permitted, "training" and other forms of academic activity is -- as long as you are not being paid.

The problem is that the only reason you'd take the NYS bar -- in the eyes of an examiner -- would be to work in the future as a lawyer in the USA. So they may raise legitimate concerns about your intent to immigrate that you will have to dispel.  See for example this internet post [here where the poster was denied because of insufficient ties to his home country](http://www.immihelp.com/forum/showthread.php/122751-Visitor-B1-B2-Visa-just-got-rejected!!!).

You may need to come up with a convincing reason why you'd want to take the NYS bar exam but then return to work as an attorney in your home country.